# How to retrieve an array in URL?

Tags: php, arrays, json, url

Trying to get data following a shopping cart purchase on the success page but having issues with `$_GET`.  The URL is:

> http://domain.com/success.php?customer[email]=email%40gmail.com&order[button][description]=music+download&order[button][id]=89765464465423184847654556&order[button][name]=music&order[button][repeat]=&order[button][resource_path]=%2Fv2%2Fcheckouts%2F9db9d0ef-9cfd-52b9-b2d7-792683d2431d&order[button][subscription]=false

How can I parse the data from this in PHP?

Comment: `echo $_GET['customer']['email'];` etc...

Answer (score 0):

If you print_r $_GET variable, then it will produce output:

```
Array
(
    [customer] => Array
        (
            [email] => email@gmail.com
        )

    [order] => Array
        (
            [button] => Array
                (
                    [description] => music download
                    [id] => 89765464465423184847654556
                    [name] => music
                    [repeat] => 
                    [resource_path] => /v2/checkouts/9db9d0ef-9cfd-52b9-b2d7-792683d2431d
                    [subscription] => false
                )

        )

)
```

That means you can access your data via $_GET['customer']['email'] and $_GET['order']['button']['description'] etc..

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are using what is called a query string. In order to retrieve the information from the query string, the `$_GET` super global exists and you can use it as follows:

```
$customer_email = $_GET['customer']['email'];
$order_button_description = $_GET['order']['button']['description'];
$order_button_id = $GET['order']['button']['id'];
// etc.
```

Let me know if that helps.